# MVC deployment on inner directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I have my simple static site (http://www.unifiedexpert.com) running on a windows server. The site is accessible and working fine. I was thinking to deploy a demo site on an inner directory to demo something to one of my clients.

I created a new directory on root location and placed demo site contents inside e.g. http://www.unifiedexpert.com/texvitplus. When I try to access the demo site it gives 403 - Forbidden: Access denied error. The demo MVC site works fine if I deploy on root directory http://www.unifiedexpert.com.

Is there any possibility to deploy a site on inner/subdirectories. I tried this kind of deployment many times on PHP servers and it worked fine.

Comment: Go in IIS > Select Folder > Right Click > Convert To Application

Comment: Have you checked that the IIS service account has permissions to the deployment folder?